# Webpack Cannot find module ./lib/api/node.js @ multi main

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I removed all `node_modules` from my project and installed it again.

Before removing them everything was working fine. Now I'm getting an error at the end of webpack build :

[image]

After it happened I:

- uninstalled webpack completely with -g option, installed it locally with `npm install` in my project.
- uninstalled nodejs completely both with `brew` and manually removing all suspected files related to `node` or `npm`
- installed nodejs with `brew` again.

Unfortunatelly I'm still getting the same error.

When I try to run the project with `npm run dev` where dev in `package.json` file is: `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors"`

I'm getting the following error :

[image]

where `./app/index.jsx` is the entry file for my project

Before all was fine, the directory structure was indentical, I haven't touched anything in the project apart from removing `node_modules` and installing it all again.

> webpack version: 1.13.2 node version: 7.0.0 webpack-dev-server
>   version: 1.16.2

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question just in case someone encounters the same issue:

I did the following steps:

- remove `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` from the `package.json` file
- remove `node_modules` folder
- run `npm install`
- install both again (latest versions) `npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-dev-server`

After installing them the versions are as follows:

> webpack: 1.13.3 (was 1.13.2 before) | webpack-dev-server: 1.16.2

Done!

Comment: This worked...no idea why but it did. For the record, I started getting this error after using `yarn` to install dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.remove foldernode_modules
2.run npm install
```

thx! my problems is solved by these two steps only !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).